# Prediction based on predicted data

Tags: data, prediction

may I ask if anyone of you knows well references on the prediction method based on the predicted data? By prediction based on the predicted data, I mean for example I have constructed a predictive model (via machine learning or any other method) using the current state $u_0$ to predict the next state $u_1$, then in the next step, I use the predicted $u_1$ to get $u_2$, and so on. My experience with LSTM seems to indicate that this way the prediction will deteriorate very quickly.

Comment: I don't know much about the topic but the general concept is called *error propagation*. As far as I know, the only thing you can do is calculate the error, but I don't think there's any way to fix it.

Comment: This is not a prediction *method*, it emerges due to the nature of some problems and models (and combinations of them). It is unclear what *exactly* you are asking about here.